# How to delete minimum and maximum from array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop

I'm a newbie in java. I'm trying to find minimum maximum element in array and then delete the minimum and maximum. This is the code I wrote, it's only working for maximum not for minimum.

```java
public class delminmax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] nums = {10,50,20,90,22};
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i]> max)
                max = nums[i];
        }
        
        System.out.println("The max number is "+ max);

        for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
            if (max==nums[i]) {
                for (int j=i; j<nums.length-1;j++)
                    nums[j]= nums[j+1];
                
            }
        for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++)
            System.out.print(nums[i]+ " " + "\n");
        
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i]< min)
                min = nums[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The min number is "+ min);
        
        
        for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
            if (min==nums[i]) {
                for (int j=i; j<nums.length-1;j++)
                    nums[j]= nums[j+1];
                
            }
        for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++)
            System.out.println(nums[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What value does `min` start with? Given that, when is `nums[i]< min` true? What's a more suitable starting number for `min`?

Comment: So i can do int min = nums[0]; Thanks

Comment: You can't really delete anything from an array.  You can emulate deletion by creating a shorter array without the value you want to remove.  Then assign the new array to your variable.  Have you learned about methods?  That would help a little.

Comment: Streams are very nice for problems like this. `int min = Arrays.stream(nums).min(Integer::compare).orElse(0); int max = Arrays.stream(nums).max(Integer::compare).orElse(0); int result = Arrays.stream(nums).filter(x -> x != min && x != max).toArray(int[]::new);`. This creates the new array `result`. As others have said, you can't shorten a Java array.

Comment: Also consider what you want to do if the maximum comes twice in the array and what to do if the array is empty (has length 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete elements from an array, an array has a fixed length determined at creation time. You can instead create a new array with two fewer elements. You only need one loop to determine the `min` and `max`, but instead of doing so directly it's cleaner in my opinion to track the indices of the `min` and `max` elements. Then you can use a second loop to skip those elements when you copy `nums` to the new array. Like,

```
int[] nums = { 10, 50, 20, 90, 22 };
int mini = 0, maxi = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] < nums[mini]) {
        mini = i;
    }
    if (nums[i] > nums[maxi]) {
        maxi = i;
    }
}
System.out.printf("The min = %d, the max = %d%n", nums[mini], nums[maxi]);
int[] newNums = new int[nums.length - 2]; // A new array, with two fewer elements
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (i != mini && i != maxi) {
        newNums[p++] = nums[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newNums));
```

Which outputs

```
The min = 10, the max = 90
[50, 20, 22]
```

Comment: This only works if the min and max aren't repeated.

Comment: @Gene **And** if there are more than 2 numbers. Actually works fine to remove the first occurence of each. Further corner cases left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You can modify it to work with multiple values of min and max.  Use the value of min or max plus a count of min or max to do the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8**

*You can try by using `streams` with the approach below:*

***Approach Here:***

I have converted the given array of Integers in the `sorted` list and then find the minimum and maximum integer from that list using any of the below method and then filtered the `nums` Array with these `min` and `max` integers and converted the filtered list back to *Array of Integers*.

**To find the minimum and maximum integer in an array**

*1) By using IntSummaryStatistics from stream*

```
IntSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.stream(nums).summaryStatistics();
        int minNum = statistics.getMin();
        int maxNum = statistics.getMax();
```

*2) By Sorting the array*

```
List<Integer> mainList = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().sorted()
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
        int minNum = mainList.get(0);
        int maxNum = mainList.get(mainList.size()-1);
```

**Note:** *It will remove all the occurrences of minimum and maximum integer from the given array.*

```
    public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] nums = {10,50,90,20,5,90,22,5};
        
        IntSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.stream(nums).summaryStatistics();
        int minNum = statistics.getMin();
        int maxNum = statistics.getMax();

        int[] num = Arrays.stream(nums)
                           .filter(x -> x != minNum && x != maxNum).toArray();
        for(int i:num){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Testcases:**

```
Input: {10,50,90,20,5,90,22,5}
Output: 10 50 20 22

Input: {10, 50, 20, 90, 22}
Output: 50 20 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are something whose length/size can't be changed. They are created with a fixed size which can't be modified. If you want to use the functionality you mentioned, it's better to go for a list, preferably ArrayList

```
List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You can always return an ArrayList as an array if need be. You can search for functions like

```
list.toArray()
```